# Check out my angular.js code, it's not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm copying my code exactly from an egghead.io tutorial but it isn't working. The angular expression isn't posting to the view properly (it posts with the `{{}}` rather than evaluating).  It works if I remove `ng-controller` from the `<body>` and the value "app" from `ng-app` in the `<html>` so I can't figure out where to pinpont the problem.  I've tried moving the script for the angular module/controller all over the html page (header, bottom of page, etc.) and no luck.

---

As a side question I'm wondering if Stackoverflow is the proper place to post this.  Supposedly you're not supposed to use the 'code-review' tag and reviews of "other-wise working code" belongs on codereview.stack.  My code is working sooo...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script>
angular.module("app", [])
.controller(FirstCtrl, function FirstCtrl()[
    var first = this;
    first.greeting = "First";
])
</script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="FirstCtrl as first">
<input type="text" ng-model="first.greeting"/>
<div ng-class="first.greeting">
    {{first.greeting}} {{World}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working with your code? The only thing i see odd is `{{World}}`

Comment: There are typos throughout your code.. you might need to work on copy paste skills. `function () []` isn't valid, `FirstCtrl` isn't defined (that should be a string), `World` isn't defined on scope and therefore won't output,

Comment: @Kevin B In my question I stated the expression isn't evaluating.  You get {{first.greeting}} {{ World}} posted to the view rather than "First World" and typing into the input in the view doesn't do anything.  It works when you remove the directive and directive values I mentioned.  Also whoever downvoted my question i'd appreciate if you let me know why.

Comment: as far as the why for downvote, **see both of my previous comments.**

Comment: @Kevin B sorry, comment delay.  I'll check out the things you mentioned

Comment: Anything inside of `{{}}` will be executed as if it is javascript. therefore, `{{World}}` is going to output whatever is in the `$scope.World` property, which in this case would be undefined, so it outputs empty string. removing `{{}}` would make it instead print `World`

Comment: @Kevin B Fixed the syntax errors: {} instead of [] and "" around World and FirstCtrl.  Good news is {{World}} now says World.  {{first.greeting}} is gone as well but unforunately it wasn't replaced by the value in the controller ("First").  Wish I could post a screenshot in comment to show everything else is same.  **As far as the downvote** I was asking for a code-review of what I did and {{World}} wasn't the only problem so I still don't understand your reasoning, please reverse if you can.  I could maybe see someone downvoting because this is the wrong site to post but my OP addresses that.

Comment: @Kevin B "what I did **wrong**"; "everything is the same as **tutorial** (typos)

Comment: The downvote isn't due to something you did wrong, it's the quality of the post.  things like syntax errors should be fixed before posting, they can be easily found in the console. If that was fixed in the question, i could remove it, but, that would invalidate existing answers.

Comment: As far as code review goes, this question isn't on topic there, because your code wasn't working.

Comment: @Kevin B My question was about specifically asking what syntax errors I made, I thought that probably would have been a given.  I'm not arrogant enough to think angular.js is broken and I believe the question about codereview.stack alludes to my intent.  I don't have a console because I'm stuck coding on my phone (laptop is unavailable).  I only mentioned {{World}} because you said to refer to your two previous comments.  Please reverse the downvote if you can.

Comment: @Kevin B Thanks for clarifying about codereview.stack.  I thought that might be the case so I decided to post here since my question was in the context of a syntax error.

Comment: I don't think you should code on your phone and then ask what your syntax errors are because you didn't have access to a console. That's a waste of people's time.

Comment: @jakeed1 Just trying to learn while my phone is the only option.  I've taken away some good habits from this post and this shouldn't happen too offen.  If it does I'll make sure the nature of my question is clear in the title.  Should be enough for people who want to avoid proofreading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        angular.module("app", [])
                .controller("FirstCtrl", [ function () {
                    var first = this;
                    first.greeting = "First";
                }
        ])
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="FirstCtrl as first">
<input type="text" ng-model="first.greeting"/>
<div ng-class="first.greeting">
    {{first.greeting}} {{World}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I made a slight change to your code.

The Controller name needed double qoutes around it see "FirstCtrl" also you had a missing square bracket and closing bracket. Copy and past the above code it should work.

It works for me. :)

Comment: Thank you everything seems to be working now.  Are the [] around the function neccessary? they weren't in the example I'm following and seems to work without them

Comment: double vs single quotes aren't important as long as they match. The `[]` were used incorrectly in code in question and should have wrapped function to create dependency array for minimizing code

Comment: @charlietfl didn't know I was supposed to wrap the function in square brackets.  Haven't learned about dependecy arrays yet, apart from in the module.  I'll be sure to look it up, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your copying went wrong somewhere , controller name should be a string

Change:

```
.controller(FirstCtrl...
```

to

```
.controller('FirstCtrl'...
```

You should have seen errors thrown in console to give you clues about this

Comment: Thanks eveeythings working now.  Unfortunately I dont have my laptop so I'm coding on my phone